# Weird Date results

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to pass a date to my obj and not sure why but the date changes for no reason and trying to see why. Anyone has a clue?

```
for(var i = 0; i<this.scheduleMonths.length; i++){
                var obj = {};

                let MyDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);
                console.log('let MyDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(MyDate));

                let MyDateString;

                MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getMonth() + i);
                console.log('MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getMonth() + i);');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(MyDate));

                MyDateString = MyDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                console.log('MyDateString = MyDate.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2);');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(MyDateString));

                obj.Name = this.scheduleMonths[i];
                obj.Opportunity__c = this.recordId;
                obj.Scheduled_Month__c = MyDateString;
                objArray.push(obj);
        }
```

Here is the result!

```
let MyDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value);
"2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getMonth() + i);
"2021-04-04T00:00:00.000Z"
NaN 
"2021-04-03" 
let MyDate = new Date(this.opportunity.data.fields.Start_Date__c.value); 
"2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z" 
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getMonth() + i); 
"2021-04-05T00:00:00.000Z" 
NaN 
"2021-04-04" 
Result Schedules 
[{"Name":"April 2021","Opportunity__c":"0067h00000BIjPyAAL","Scheduled_Month__c":"2021-04-03"},{"Name":"May 2021","Opportunity__c":"0067h00000BIjPyAAL","Scheduled_Month__c":"2021-04-04"}]
```

the first line is right, the date is indeed 2021-04-29 but the second line is wrong. the date should stay the same because I am incrementing the month by the index i (0) than i (1)...

Please help
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setDate` sets the day part of the date, you're probably looking for `setMonth`.  [Here's the documentation on the Date class.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: What can I say? Rookie? lol thanks, not use to play with dates...